# Time formatting not working Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

The WebService returns `232351`, I would like to format the time in `23:23:51`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBFiB.gif)

I tried this, but the format is not correct.

```
{{ (lastConnexionMoment$ | async)?.lastConnexionDate  | date: 'HH:mm:ss' }}
```

Comment: Webservice is returning a string or a number?

Comment: @robert: a number...

Comment: Can you create a http://www.stackblitz.com